# Tabulate Alignment and Indentation

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, indentation

I'm documenting the Python class I've built at my company.

I'm struggling to make a table with the first column vertically centralized and the descriptions at the second column indented like this:

[image]

This is what I've come up so far, everything is fine except the vertical alignment and the indentation of the description

```
\documentclass[pt,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\begin{document}
{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\begin{tabular}{|c l l}
\textcolor{blue}{qrcap.Serie} & \textit{Class} \\ \hline \hline
Parameters: & \multicolumn{2}{p{9cm}}{\raggedright \textbf{parameter1} : \textit{string} \newline{} Description 1. \bigbreak \textbf{parameter2} : \textit{pandas.DataFrame} \\ Description2} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any insights on how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why do you define three columns (`{|c l l}`)  but only use two of them?

Comment: Thanks! I was doing some tests and I forgot to return to only two columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using `multirow` to vertically center the contents of the left column, `tabularx` to make the table as wide as the textwidth and `\multicolumn{1}{@{\quad\quad}X}{...}` for the indentation:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c X}
\textcolor{blue}{qrcap.Serie}& \textit{Class} \\ \hline \hline
\multirow{5}{*}{Parameters:} & \textbf{parameter1} : \textit{string} \\
                             & \multicolumn{1}{@{\quad\quad}X}{Description 1.} \\
                             & \textbf{parameter2} : \textit{pandas.DataFrame} \\ 
                             & \multicolumn{1}{@{\quad\quad}X}{Description2 Description2 Description2 Description2  Description2}   \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose  to use a custom `description` environment nested in an `X` column:

```
    \documentclass[pt,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{fourier, cabin}
    \usepackage{linegoal, enumitem}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \usepackage{scrextend}
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
    \makeatother
    \begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \sffamily
    \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\compress\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lX@{}}%
    \textcolor{blue}{qrcap.Serie} & \textit{Class} \\ \hline \hline
    Parameters & \smallskip
    \begin{description}[font =\sffamily, after=\vspace*{-\topsep}]
    \item[parameter1 :] \textit{string} \newline
    Description 1.
    \item[parameter2 :]\textit{pandas.DataFrame} \newline
    Description2.
    \end{description}
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}

    \end{document}
```

[image]